# Easy way to keep counting up infinitely

Tags: python

What's a good way to keep counting up infinitely? I'm trying to write a condition that will keep going until there's no value in a database, so it's going to iterate from 0, up to theoretically infinity (inside a try block, of course).

How would I count upwards infinitely? Or should I use something else?

I am looking for something similar to i++ in other languages, where it keeps iterating until failure.

Comment: Also, why doesn't Python have i++? Literally every other language I've worked in does, and it seems like a glaring hole.

Comment: 1) `i++` is syntactic sugar and I doubt that you can call it's exclusion a "glaring hole". 2) Python uses `i += 1` because it is more explicit about the increment. 3) Guido decided it was so.

Comment: i+=1 is only one more character

Comment: @AndrewAlexander *"There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it."*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Take a look at [itertools.count()](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.count).

From the docs:

> `count(start=0, step=1)` --> count object
>
> Make an iterator that returns evenly spaced values starting with `n`.
>   Equivalent to:

```
def count(start=0, step=1):
    # count(10) --> 10 11 12 13 14 ...
    # count(2.5, 0.5) -> 2.5 3.0 3.5 ...
    n = start
    while True:
        yield n
        n += step
```

So for example:

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.count(13):
   print(i)
```

would generate an infinite sequence starting with 13, in steps of +1. And, I hadn't tried this before, but you can count down too of course:

```
for i in itertools.count(100, -5):
    print(i)
```

starts at 100, and keeps subtracting 5 for each new value ....

---

Comment: I just couldn't stand the SO auto code formatter incorrect colors :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit smaller code than what the other user provided!

```
x = 1
while True:
    x = x+1
    print x
```

Comment: I like `count` but this is also valid and can come in handy if you need multiple counters. Would update to `x += 1`

Answer (score 0):

A little shorter, using an iterator and no library:

```
x = 0
for x in iter(lambda: x+1, -1):
    print(x)
```

But it requires a variable in the current scope.

Comment: Technically works, but the interaction between the `lambda` and the loop variable is unusual and easy to miss. For code clarity, `itertools.count` is better.

Comment: I couldn't agree more.

Answer (score 0):

> this easier using no library and i got it from the upper code but there was an  issue that , in the print line he just added print x

```
x = 1
while True:
   x = x+1
   print (f'{x}')
```