# Why is my code skipping the entire "for i in range" loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, range

I've come across an issue where my code is skipping the `for` loop with all the input prompts and is going straight to the printing of the lists below the loop.

What is wrong and how can I fix this?

```
import statistics

Age = list()
SaturnRT = list()
MarsRT = list()
Mars = list()
Saturn = list()
Houses = ['saturn', 'Saturn', 'Mars', 'mars']
CheckList = ['Saturn', 'saturn']
ReactionTime = list()
inputVar = None


for i in range(0, ):
    print("enter age: ")
    while inputVar != type(int):
        try:
            inputVar = int(input())
            while inputVar>16 or inputVar<12:
                print("error! invalid entry")
                inputVar = int(input("enter the age: "))
            break
        except:
            print("enter an integer! ")
    Age.append(inputVar)

    print("enter reaction time (ms): ")
    while inputVar != type(float):
        try:
            inputVar = float(input())
            while inputVar < 0 or inputVar > 500:
                print("enter a valid time! ")
                inputVar = float(input())
            House = str(input("enter the house: "))
            while House not in Houses:
                print("error! invalid entry")
                House = str(input("enter the house: "))
            if House in CheckList:
                SaturnRT.append(inputVar)
                Saturn.append(House)
            else:
                MarsRT.append(inputVar)
                Mars.append(House)
            break
        except:
            print("enter an valid time! ")
    ReactionTime.append(inputVar)

print(SaturnRT)
print(MarsRT)
print("saturn reaction times avg: ", statistics.mean(SaturnRT))
print("saturn fastest time: ", min(SaturnRT))
print("saturn slowest time: ", max(SaturnRT))
print("mars reaction times avg: ", statistics.mean(MarsRT))
print("mars fastest time: ", min(MarsRT))
print("mars slowest time: ", max(MarsRT))

print(ReactionTime)
print(Age)
```

Comment: What do you think `range(0, )` means?

Comment: Maybe it's an infinite loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`range(0, )` is equivalent to `range(0)` (see also: [Should I add a trailing comma after the last argument in a function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087742/should-i-add-a-trailing-comma-after-the-last-argument-in-a-function-call)).

But `range(0)` is an empty range. Iterating over it results in a loop with zero iterations, i.e., the whole `for` loop is skipped.

If you want a loop that goes on until a `break` statement is encountered inside, use `while True:` instead of `for i in range(0, ):`.

You seem to be not using the `i` variable, but if you do want to count the iterations in such a loop, you can use `itertools.count` (see: [Easy way to keep counting up infinitely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11424808/easy-way-to-keep-counting-up-infinitely) or [Count iterations in while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38620745/count-iterations-in-while-loop)):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for i in itertools.count():
...     print(i)
...     if i > 3:
...         break
... 
0
1
2
3
4
```